Dell VLT - rebooting a downstream node causes it to lose connection until a cable is replugged
We have some Dell servers connected to a pair of top-of-rack Dell S5232F-ON switches running OS10, we've tried to configure VLT on the switches so that each server can have a connection to both switches and hopefully we'll have redundancy and possibly some extra bandwidth.
It seems to be working fine, but if I reboot one of the servers the connection remains down for the OS until I unplug and replug one of the transceivers in the server (or switch), then it springs into life.
We followed these docs to set up the switches: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-uk/smartfabric-os10-emp-partner/smartfabric-os-user-guide-10-5-6/configure-vlt?guid=guid-d858a76d-b0ed-46ce-a7dd-0624235d92bc&lang=en-us
The servers are running Ubuntu 24.04 and are configured with the two ports (one to each switch) in a bond, with a bridge on top for running containers/VMs. I've tried a few different transmit hash policies (layer 2 + 3, layer 3 + 4, encap 3 + 4) on the servers in case that made a difference, but it doesn't seem to.
Any advice gratefully received :)
